# libdvdcss2 install-cs.sh not completing on PowerPC Mac (or other achitectures besides x86)

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dvd, arm, powerpc

Did an install of Lubuntu 12.04 a few days ago, and managed to get libdvdcss2 installed - all good, then I mucked up the installation because I'm a noob, and could no longer install Libdvdcss2.  So, decided to get latest 14.04 version and install on my iMac PPC G4 system, all good until I try to install libdvdcss2.  This is what I did....

1. Installed OS (Lubunto 14.04 PowerPC 32bit) & updated
2. Rebooted
3. installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`
4. ran `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` script which seemed to work, right up till the end, then got the following error:

   ```
   --2014-07-16 16:51:09--  http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss_1.2.13.orig.tar.gz
   Resolving download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)... 88.191.250.9, 2a01:e0d:1:3:58bf:fa02:0:2
   Connecting to download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)|88.191.250.9|:80... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
   2014-07-16 16:51:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.
   ```

So, to me it looks like the script is trying to download a specific file `libdvdcss_1.2.13.orig.tar.gz`, when I browse the source, it doesn't exist!

What does this mean?  Is it a case that the VLC people have pulled the file, or is the script wrong?

Either way, UBUNTU & Lubuntu Noobs like me are not getting DVD playback!  can someone here point me to the correct way for installing the codecs?

Many Thanks

Comment: I just tried the script just now and it worked fine... although you are on ppc, I bet they don't have packaged versions for that architecture...

Answer (score 3):

## For all architectures

Unfortunately the VideoLAN Project team only provides pre-built packages of libdvdcss2 for Intel x86 architectures (see below). Therefore for PowerPC, ARM and other architectures you must compile and build it yourself as described here:

1. Add the VideoLAN package repository to your repository list, add the repository key and update the repository index. In the commands below replace `trusty` with the name of your Ubuntu (or Debian) release (see the output of `lsb_release -sc` if you don't know). (Currently the most recent suppported release name is `utopic`. The old packages should still work for newer releases though.)

   ```sh
   printf '%s http://download.videolan.org/pub/ubuntu/trusty / #VideoLAN Project\n' deb deb-src | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.d/videolan-project.list
   wget -O - https://download.videolan.org/pub/ubuntu/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   <sup>([Source](//www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html), modified for Ubuntu)</sup>
2. Change to a directory where you have write privileges and want to compile and build the package, e. g.:

   ```sh
   cd /tmp
   ```
3. Install the build dependencies, download the package sources and compile them:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo apt-get build-dep libdvdcss2
   apt-get source --compile libdvdcss2
   ```
4. If successful, the current directory should contain a few `.deb` files. Install the relevant one and you're done:

   ```sh
   sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_*_$(dpkg --print-architecture).deb
   ```

   Where `*` will be matched and substituted automatically by the just compiled version of libdvdcss2 (currently 1.2.13-0).

## For PCs and Intel Macs

Instead of building the library yourself, you can install a pre-compiled and packaged version from the VideoLAN project:

1. Same as step 1 for all architecures (see above).
2. `sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2`