# libdvdcss2 depackaging error (12.04 precise)

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, dvd

I previously [asked a question regarding DVD playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769679/cannot-play-contents-of-external-dvd-drive-on-arm-based-computer) and after much back and forth with David Foerster, he was able to narrow down the problem. With that in mind, I am now asking for further help! David linked me to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498620/libdvdcss2-install-cs-sh-not-completing-on-powerpc-mac-or-other-achitectures-be). I can follow the instructions up to step 4, however, when I try to run that command, the console returns `dpkg-deb: error: unknown option -i`. I am sure there must be a very simple solution, however, my knowledge of Ubuntu is incredibly limited. Can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `dpkg` instead of `dpkg-deb` to install the packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_*_$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_ARCH).deb
```

I've changed that in the linked thread.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that particular issue, however, it seems that the main DVD problem still stands. The computer doesn't recognise the DVD, and though I can mount it and see the files, it will not play. This seems to apply to all my commercially-bought DVDs